# How font-size em value work?

Tags: css

Im using em font sizes, which is working fine for everywhere apart from the sidebar.

In the main content the em size is great. If I copy this em size to the sidebar the text becomes larger.

Im using a html/body size of 17px. Then 1.412em to get the size I would like. To see a live link of the sidebar font bigger go to this [link](http://www.probablybest.co). If you look at the twitter feed on the right sidebar you will see its using the same em but you view it a lot larger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using em as measurement value would just not inhert but increases accordingly.

Here's an example:

```
<div>
  <p>
    <span>foo bar</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

---

```
body{
  font-size: 1em;
}
div{
  font-size: 1.5em;/*1.5em of 1em == 1.5em*/
}
div > p{
  font-size: 1.5em;/*1.5em of 1.5em inherited from div == 2.25em*/
}
div > p > span{
  font-size: 1.5em; /*1.5em of 2.25em inherited from p == 3.375em*/
}
```

So, I would recommend you to use px as measurement value.

---

> Use ems to make scalable style sheets only.

---

If you want to know more about `px`, `em`, and `%` please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609517/why-em-instead-of-px) and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474107/what-is-em-font-size-how-much-is-it-in-pixels)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `em` for `font-size`, that's just about the only place where you should **never** use it.

`1em` is the size of an `m` in the current standard font. You can use this to set paddings/margins, for example between paragraphs or around text blocks, that need to scale according to font size, to cater for people using custom settings at OS/browser level, or just as an easy way to keep a 'good' distance without having to worry about precise pixels.

Scaling a font to a relative size to the `m` of the current standard font makes no sense at all, [unless you want to achieve this effect](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/jtvox3kh/). If you would want to, it would be more logical to specify `font-size:110%`, for a single element or block. As a rule, use `pt` or `px` to specify font sizes.