# What is concrete font size of formatted text?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to render some text on DrawingContext object, which should have font size, specified in pt units. For this purpose I am using FormattedText object. But this object has weird (for me) constructor:

```
public FormattedText(string textToFormat, CultureInfo culture, FlowDirection flowDirection, Typeface typeface, double emSize, Brush foreground);
```

It requires that font size should be in em units. But as far as I know, one em unit equals the current font size. How can I know that font size?

Comment: Do you want to convert pixels to em or what? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4474107/1997232).

Comment: Which entity has a "current font"? A `DrawingContext` object does not have a current font.

Comment: I took this definition from short and well descriptive for me article: http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Comment: According to the help for that constructor, the em size is `The font size for the text's em measure, provided in device-independent units (1/96th inch per unit).` [See here for an example of converting from em size to points](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752098(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, both articles helped me